# JavaFX: How to make a ScrollPane pan only on middle button?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

JavaFX's ScrollPane panes on all mouse events when allowed to pan:

```
scrollPane.setPannable(true);
```

How to limit the ScrollPane to pan only on middle mouse events, while still allowing all events to get to the StackPane's content?

Answer (score 8):

You should consume all events except the middle button events inside the content's event handler:

```
// Let the ScrollPane.viewRect only pan on middle button.
imageLayer.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
    if(event.getButton() != MouseButton.MIDDLE) event.consume();
});
```

This works because the ScrollPane pans via an event handler too, and event handlers are invoked bottom-up. Thus if we consume the event via the child, it won't get to the ScrollPane viewRect which does the panning.

Comment: Suppose you actually need to handle left and/or right mouse button events on some nodes that are inside the scroll pane, though. Does this prevent that, or will those still work?

Comment: @James_D It does work! Because all handlers are executed on a node, even if one of the handlers consumes the event. If it's consumed in an event handler, it won't bubble up to parents. If consumed in an event filter, it won't go down to children.

Answer (score 1):

Once `setPannable` looks for `MouseDrag` event, you can set and unset pannable in `MousePressed` and `MouseReleased`:

```
ScrollPane sp = ...
sp.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
  if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) sp.setPannable(true);
});
sp.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
  if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) sp.setPannable(false);
});
```